# How to convert a List to Json in c# EF core web api

Tags: c#, json, list, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am unable to convert to return a json instead of a list. I tried using Newtonsoft.Json, but nothing worked. Either the error or returns null.

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            using (var context = new ProjectContext())
            {

                var MyEntity = context.User.ToList();

                return MyEntity; 
            }
        }
```

User Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Order= new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Tel{ get; set; }
        public float? Stars{ get; set; }

        public virtual SellerSeller { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Order{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

The type of returns from MyEntity is System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: Can you show us return JSON, Type of `MyEntity` with its model

Comment: make sure `MyEntity ` is not null first then use `return Json(new {date = MyEntity , Status = "success"})`

Comment: is `context.User` returning some something? what is value in `MyEntity`

Comment: When u used newtonsoft, did the listed object have the serialization attributes on its properties? [JsonProperty]

Comment: @JamesLoForti I did it with ```var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize (aList) ;```. I was giving an error because of the return of the wrong method. Noob error.

Comment: @JamesLoForti please comment your solution so i can take it for granted and close the discussion.

Comment: I was under the impression you were using c# core. The C# line would be more like: var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);

Comment: @JamesLoForti yes, sorry. My mistake kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        using (var context = new ProjectContext())
        {

            var MyEntity = context.User.ToList();

            return Ok(MyEntity); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to return as Json

```
return Json(new { data = MyEntity,  Status = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: i am getiing this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Models.User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)